# Get IK using `ur_modern_driver`

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ur-modern-driver, ur-driver, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get Inverse Kinematics using the `ur_modern_driver`? Something similar to the UR Script function: `get_inverse_kin(x, qnear, maxPositionError=1e-10, maxOrientationError=1e-10)`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288385/get-ik-using-%60ur_modern_driver%60/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not functionality the `ur_modern_driver` provides. The driver is not a bridge into the VM that runs your URScript on the controller, but interfaces with the external motion and input/output capabilities of the controller.

---

A typical ROS approach would be to either use the services provided by MoveIt (if you're using MoveIt already, see [Kinematic Model Tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/kinematics/src/doc/kinematic_model_tutorial.html) for instance), or load an IK plugin directly into your application / script and use that.

`trac_ik` was recently extended with Python wrappers, see [wiki/trac_ik](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik). You could perhaps use that.

Another alternative could be KDL. There are both C++ and Python interfaces to that available, see [wiki/orocos_kinematics_dynamics](http://wiki.ros.org/orocos_kinematics_dynamics). Note that this may be slightly involved to get working, as it doesn't seem to have been updated much over the past few years.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-04-12**:
Thanks, however if I'd like to use UR inbuilt IK solver, I am publishing the following:
`pub = rospy.Publisher('/ur_driver/URScript', String, queue_size=10) query= "get_inverse_kin((10,150,100,0,0,0))" pub_command = "%s \n" % (query) pub.publish(pub_command)` ...

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-04-12**:
... The function must return the closest joint positions. However, I'm not able to see anything on the topic `/ur_driver/URScript`. Is the topic just for sending commands?

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-04-12**:
Okay. Is there a workaround or should I set up a separate client-server application to access the IK solver?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
You cannot do that. The controller does not return any results from statements sent to it over port `TCP30002`, `TCP30003` or `TCP30004`. So the driver cannot return anything to you either.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
There is no workaround, as the UR controller just doesn't return any results from URScript statements sent to it over a network connection. That is not a restriction of the driver, but of the controller.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
You could see whether creating a client-server application works for you. Note that the driver is also partly a URScript program, and you cannot run multiple programs on the controller, so you'll have to carefully manage those two.